# Terraform parsing error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am new to Terraform and I'm trying to deploy a resource group using the example from the documentation found [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/azure_cli), in Visual Studio Code. I receive a json parsing error when trying to use `terraform apply` or `terraform plan`. The commands`terraform init`, `terraform fmt` and `terraform validate` all work fine. Connecting to azure using `az login` also works.

Information about code, versioning and setup can be seen below.

**Error**

```
╷
│ Error: building AzureRM Client: please ensure you have installed Azure CLI version 2.0.79 or newer. Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: unmarshaling the result of Azure CLI: invalid character 'C' looking for beginning of value.
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on main.tf line 10, in provider "azurerm":
│   10: provider "azurerm" {
│
╵
```

**Code in main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.28.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resourcegroup"
  location = "eu-west"
}
```

**az --version output**

```
azure-cli                         2.41.0

core                              2.41.0
telemetry                          1.0.8

Dependencies:
msal                            1.20.0b1
azure-mgmt-resource             21.1.0b1
```

**terraform --version output**

```
Terraform v1.2.5
on windows_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v3.28.0
```

Comment: This seems to be the source code generating this error: https://github.com/hashicorp/go-azure-helpers/blob/421cd3cfc9ae3b6c42854612bf79aaa9f0c186b7/authentication/auth_method_azure_cli_token.go#L240-L243

Comment: It seems to be running the command line `az version -o=json` and expecting that to return JSON. Does that command return valid JSON when you run it at your command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

***For installing the terraform in visual studio [refer this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/configure-vs-code-extension-for-terraform?tabs=azure-powershell)***
***We have to install the developer cli [use this link to download and install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/azure-developer-cli/get-started?tabs=baremetal&pivots=programming-language-csharp)***

***I have installed the visual studio code and install the terraform***

***Please find the versions which I have used***

[image]

***I have created terraform file***

```
vi main.tf


terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.28.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example23" {
  name     = "example-resourcegroup23"
  location = "eastus"
}
```

***I have followed some commands to run the file***

```
  Terraform init
```

[image]

```
terraform plan
```

[image]

```
terraform apply
```

[image]

***When I open the portal  I am able to see newly created resource group***

[image]

***Note:***

***1).In order to use the azure CLI, terraform should be able to do the azure cli authentication for that we have to add the token.***

***2).Both terraform and Azure cli should be on same path***

```
az account get-access-token { "accessToken": token_id", "expiresOn": <Date_with_time>, "subscription": "subscription_id", "tenant": "", "tokenType": "token_type" }***
```

***3). you can also refer this link [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14778)  for know abt the issue***